# Regular expression for replacement operation

Tags: c#

Is there any regular expression that will replace everything except alphanumeric?
My attempt (not working)

```
string str = "This is a string;;;; having;;; and It also 5555 777has dot (.) Many dots(.....)";


Regex rgx2 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
string result1 = rgx2.Replace(str, "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

The `^` symbol in your second regex means 'at start of string', the way it is written. In order to have it negate the set it needs to be the first character after opening bracket:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

However, this will remove the `-` characters that you previously replaced spaces with. You probably want to exclude that character as well:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```